# How can I ignore everything under a folder in Mercurial

Tags: version-control, mercurial, hgignore

I am looking for an expression for the .hgignore file, to ignore all files beneath a specified folder.

eg: I would like to ignore all files and folders beneath bin

Actually any advice on how the expressions are formed would be great

Answer (score 179, accepted):

Alternately:

```
syntax: glob
bin/**
```

Comment: this is much easier I think :)

Comment: PhiLho, I think that would also filter out files named bin

Comment: This answer, plus this documentation helped me: http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgignore.5.html

Comment: `bin` `bin/` `bin/*` `bin/**` - All do the same thing with glob i.e. ignore all directories & sub-directories named bin but not any file name bin.txt or bin1 . What's the point of asterix?

Comment: I like it as clarity, but certainly use 'bin' if you've internalized the glob rules (I'm a `re` sort of guy)

Comment: I have had serious problems with ignoring `bin`, it seams to be special. I can have the correct pattern and it does not work, I then use another pattern (`Debug` the only subdirectory) and the directory is ignored, then switch back to the correct one and all is ok. I have no idea where this memory is coming from.

Comment: I think that @buffer is wrong. For experience I have sow that when I use bin/ or bin/* only ignore one level and with bin/** it ignore things in bin and subfolders. But I think this is a bug or wrong interpretation of spec.

Comment: If you use TortoiseHg, here's a link about ignoring files that may be helpful. https://tortoisehg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ignore.html

Answer (score 55):

I did some experiments and I found that the regex syntax on Windows applies to the path starting with the current repository, with backslashes transformed to slashes.

So if your repository is in E:\Dev for example, `hg status` will apply the patterns against foo/bar/file1.c and such. Anchors apply to this path.

So:

- Glob applies to path elements and is rooted to element parts
- foo matches any folder (or file) named foo (not to "foobar" nor "barfoo")
- *foo* matches any folder or file with "foo" in the name
- foo/bar* matches all files in "foo" folder starting with "bar"

- Regex is case sensitive, not anchored
- Of course, backslash regex special characters like . (dot)
- / matches \ path separator on Windows. \ doesn't match this separator...
- foo matches all files and folders with "foo" inside
- foo/ matches only folders ending with "foo"
- /foo/ matches the folder "foo" somewhere in the path
- /foo/bar/ matches the folder "bar" in the folder "foo" somewhere in the path
- ^foo matches file or folder starting by foo at the root of the repository
- foo$ matches file ending with foo

I hope this will help, I found the [HGIGNORE(5)](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgignore.5.html) page a bit succinct.

Comment: I have the pattern ''[Dd]ebug*/'' in use and the strange Thing is, that it also filters **files** like ''debug.txt''

Answer (score 10):

Both of those will also filter out a directory called `cabin`, which might not be what you want. If you're filtering top-level, you can use:

```
^/bin/
```

For `bin` directories below your root, you can omit the ^. There is no need to specify syntax, regexp is the default.

Comment: This won't ignore anything.  The caret says only things in the repo root but the leading slash catches only dirs not in the repo root.

Answer (score 3):

syntax: glob
bin/**

This answer is shown above, however I'd also like to add that * and ** are handled differently. ** is recursive, * is not.

See [Hg Patterns](https://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#patterns)

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, I got it

```
syntax: regexp
bin\\*
```

expressions follow standard perl regular expression syntax.

Comment: Indeed, and your expression means "file or folder ending with bin and followed by 0 or more backslashes"... So it works because the backslash is nullified by the *, but it applies anything with "bin" inside. On Windows, hg replaces \ by / before matching.

Answer (score -2):

to ignore .class files

```
syntax: regexp
?\.class
```