# ignoring folders in mercurial

Tags: regex, mercurial, hgignore

**Caveat:**
I try all the posibilities listed here: [How can I ignore everything under a folder in Mercurial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254002/how-can-i-ignore-everything-under-a-folder-in-mercurial).
None works as I hope.

I want to ignore every thing under the folder `test`. But not ignore `srcProject\test\TestManager`

I try

```
syntax: glob
test/**
```

And it ignores `test` and `srcProject\test\TestManager`

With:

```
syntax: regexp
^/test/
```

It's the same thing.

Also with:

```
syntax: regexp
test\\*
```

I have install TortoiseHG 0.4rc2 with Mercurial-626cb86a6523+tortoisehg, Python-2.5.1, PyGTK-2.10.6, GTK-2.10.11 in Windows

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try it without the slash after the caret in the regexp version.

```
^test/
```

Here's a test:

```
~$ mkdir hg-folder-ignore
~$ cd hg-folder-ignore
~/hg-folder-ignore$ echo '^test/' > .hgignore
~/hg-folder-ignore$ hg init
~/hg-folder-ignore$ mkdir test
~/hg-folder-ignore$ touch test/ignoreme
~/hg-folder-ignore$ mkdir -p srcProject/test/TestManager
~/hg-folder-ignore$ touch srcProject/test/TestManager/dont-ignore
~/hg-folder-ignore$ hg stat
? .hgignore
? srcProject/test/TestManager/dont-ignore
```

Notice that ignoreme isn't showing up and dont-ignore is.

Comment: @JaKXz yes, this works in all versions of Mercurial.  What you've got in your `.hgignore` didn't come through.  Make sure your ignore file is being interpreted as a regex instead of a glob, and don't count on ignore to ignore files you've already `hg add`ed.  Ignoring only affects how unadded files are listed/treated.

Comment: et al. The solution I found is to use this:
`syntax: regexp
^SourceFolder\bin
^SourceFolder\gen`
and for a file named .classpath:
`^SourceFolder\.classpath`

Answer (score 4):

You can use zero-width negative look-ahead and look-behind assertions to specify that you want to ignore `test` only when it's not preceded by `srcProject` and not followed by `TestManager`:

```
syntax: regexp
(?<!srcProject\\)test\\(?!TestManager)
```

Mercurial uses Python regular expressions, so you can find more info on zero-width assertions in the Python docs: https://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax

Comment: Way more complicated than it needs to be to solve a simple problem. Ry4an's solution accomplishes the same in a much simpler manner.

Answer (score 4):

Both cases worked for me (on linux and windows):

```
syntax: regexp
^backup/     #root folder
nbproject/   #any folder
```

or

```
syntax: glob
./backup/*   #root folder
nbproject/*  #any folder
```

However, it wasn't before I added a link to .hgignore file to .hgrc file in my repo:

```
[ui]
ignore = .hg/.hgignore
```

Also worth mentioning that mercurial ignores files that it is **not currently tracking**, which are those added before you configured it to ignore them. So, don't be put off by hg status saying some filed are M (modified) or ! (missing) in the folders that you have just added to the ignore list!

Comment: `.hgignore` is normally in the root directory of the repository, not under `.hg`.

Answer (score 0):

Create .hgignore file under root directory of the repository

Now add the following contents in the file .

> syntax: glob
>
> bin/**
>
> *.DS_Store

This will remove the bin directory and all the *.DS_Store files from the repository