# Folders not being added in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I looked at this question: [ignoring folders in mercurial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310117/ignoring-folders-in-mercurial) that mentions how to ignore a folder, but that's not what I need.

I'm using TortoiseHG and after I "add" all my folders, they show still as "?" instead of "+". The files within them show "+", but the folders themselves just show "?". Is this a problem with Mercurial on Windows XP? Or, is it a problem between my keyboard and my chair?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mercurial adds only files in, and *infers* the folders from the actual file names. If you drop down to a command line and do `hg status`, you will see that folders are not listed at all. The files within the folder you added will be listed with the `A` tag, but the actual folders don't list in a hg status command.

Comment: It is quite confusing that anything even bothers to show a Mercurial status of any kind for the folders.  It shouldn't do that.

Comment: @Tarydon Thanks. I uninstalled TortoiseSVN to fix the icon problem (they share the same overlay application), but I'm glad I understand the bit about the folders. That stuff drives me nuts.
@Omnifarious I'm glad it shows folder status because when I have a file changed in a sub/sub/sub folder, I want the "!" to propagate upwards so I don't have to dig.

Comment: @orokusaki: Ahh, yes, that is a sensible thing to do then.  I don't use GUI for programming at all, and so that didn't occur to me.

Comment: It's just a context menu that gives you all the functions of HG in a few clicks. I'm a "show me the guts" kind of nerd too, but this is one place I'll gladly save time by using the GUI because the green folder icons make me feel warm and fuzzy.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to add the folders separately (in fact, Mercurial doesn't handle plain folders/directories at all). As long as your files are there, you're fine.