# Mercurial .ignore filter assistance

Tags: regex, mercurial, glob, hgignore

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ignoring folders in mercurial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310117/ignoring-folders-in-mercurial)

I'm trying to put together what I thought would be a simple ignore filter, but can't seem to get it working.

I have a /database directory in my code that contains files that change regularly and are not part of the source.  I want that directory (and all the files inside of it) ignored by Mercurial.

How can I make this work?

I've tried adding the following:

```
^DATABASE/
```

and the database directory is not ignored.

```
C:\CDM_Dev\cdm>hg status
M .hgignore
M DATABASE\CDM001.MEM
M DATABASE\audittr.CDX
M DATABASE\audittr.DBF
M Program\librptte.FXP
M Program\libupdat.FXP
M Program\rpttenan.FXP
```

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your database files are *already* controlled by Mercurial, as the `hg status` output suggests. Mercurial ignore filter is not the same thing as Subversion's *ignore on commit*; that is, new files, should they appear under `DATABASE/`, will be ignored, but any existing files will continue to be monitored for changes.

If the files under `DATABASE/` are not a part of the source, remove them from the control (`hg forget DATABASE/*`, then commit). They won't be appearing as unknowns anymore.

Comment: Also, removing the final slash from `^DATABASE/` will optimize status operations quite a bit, depending on the size of the subdirectory tree.