# how to omit a folder from mercurial versioning in netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, mercurial, version-control

i'm using netbeans with the built-in mercurial support and want to omit a sub-folder from versioning.

how do i do that?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if there is a way to do this directly from Netbeans, but you can add a .hgignore file in the root of your repository to specify what files or folders to ignore. The following links will provide all the information you might need:

http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgignore.5.html

[How can I ignore everything under a folder in Mercurial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254002/how-can-i-ignore-everything-under-a-folder-in-mercurial)

http://kiln.stackexchange.com/questions/707/how-to-exclude-bin-and-obj-folders

Answer (score 0):

This thread is old, but just in case people find it while looking for the answer...

Check this out: http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/mercurial.html

Once you've initialized the project, if you've done in a valid location (generally right in the root of the project), all the "new" files will have green filenames & the new folders will display a small blue db icon on them.  This indicates that they are not in sync with the repository and need to be committed/synced. You can select click any number of files & folders (singly or ctrl click) and choose Mercurial -> Toggle Ignore and the files will be ignored from then on.  They will also turn gray to indicate that they aren't really being paid attention to.

You'll also want the Window->Versioning->Mercurial window open when working with Mercurial.  This automatically refreshes a list of "locally" changed files that need to be synced with the repository.  If an item is listed there & you mark it to be ignored, it (& any children in case of a folder), will be removed from the list to be synced.

When you're done with a revision, you can click the "Commit All" button in the Mercurial Window/Panel to sync the new file version(s) with the repository.

See the link above for more details on how to use the features.

Note also that NetBeans supports Git, SubVersion, & Mercurial, but to use any of them you have to first install them on your machine / have a system for NetBeans to connect to.

This is how it is as of v7.0.1+ (I didn't use it before then so I don't know if there are any differences before v7.0.1)

㋛ ㋡ ㋛ ㋡ ㋛ ㋡
Todd β)